# c# append text withou waiting for onclick event to finish

Tags: c#, onclick

I am doing an c# small app with a richtextbox and a button that will check if some files exists and display the result into the richtextbox.

```
 private void RunButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      myRichTextBox.AppendText("Starting...");

      if (checkFileExists())
      {
          myRichTextBox.AppendText("File exists.");
      }
      else
      {
          myRichTextBox.AppendText("File NOT exists!");
      }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that the text "Starting..." is appended into the richtextbox when the checkFileExists() has finished. Since this one can take some time I would like to display the "Starting" message at the beginning and the rest of text messages when checkFileExists has finished.

Can you help me with that?

thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to look at how the BackgroundWorker class could help you. When the code enters the event handler any change you make to the UI appearance is not executed until you exit from the event handler.

Comment: I belive checking files on disc in .NET are async then you can use async await then

Comment: Thanks Steve and miechooy for your answers. I have found this video that is explaining what i need: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C5VhaxQWcpE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the text on the main thread, then start the long running process (checking whether the file exists) on a separate thread.  Once that's finished you can update the text with the result - but that would have to be marshalled back to the main (UI) thread.

Here's one way to do it.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Text = "Starting...";

    var uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CheckIfFileExists(uiScheduler));
}

private async Task CheckIfFileExists(TaskScheduler uiScheduler)
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);

    var exists = true; // check if exists

    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => UpdateText(exists), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, uiScheduler).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

private void UpdateText(bool exists)
{
    button1.Text = $"Exists: {exists}.";
}
```

Comment: Hi PeteGo, thanks for your answer. I found a video on youtube explaining what I was looking for (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C5VhaxQWcpE) but I will test your solution since I think will fit better to my needs.